# Auto code generator to consume web services from Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2 to consume web services from Android projects. Everything is working fine but I miss some properties in the library which I think are pretty common.

In Visual Studio when adding a web service reference all the necessary code so you can consume the web service is created, and even more important, the necessary classes for the objects/types returned by the web service. The same can be done in XCode or in Eclipse when using Java EE.

The closer I get to this in Android is http://code.google.com/p/android-soap-enabler/wiki/FiveMinutesTutorial I tried but I had some problems and I let it go.

It's hard to believe that there is no standard way to solve this issue. I mean, I guess there exists so many Android Apps consuming web services, and no one has a better way than manually parse the xml response using the ksoap2 library? What finally makes it even weird, is that I didn't find anyone asking this question. Is it so strange what I'm asking? Am I the first one with this problem?

I would like to know if there is any tool/library/project/whatever which automatically creates the necessary code for consuming the web services.